# How to Have "Destination Host Unreachable" when pinging return a value of 1 and not 0

Tags: python, ip-address, ping

I am using python to code a program that will ping a device, and do nothing if it gets a response back from the device, but if it does not receive any response, it will send me an email to notify me that the device may be down. However, as has been mentioned on here before, when the response from the ping is "Destination Host Unreachable," the return value is 0, which is the same as if it received a response. So what I'm looking for is help with how to discern the Destination Host Unreachable from the actual response so I can have an email sent to me under that condition (since it means the device is most likely down).

```
import platform
import subprocess
import smtplib
import time

#Delay to wait for Rigs to Boot
#time.sleep(600)

a = 1
while 1==1:
    #Ping other PC's
    def myping(host):
    parameter = '-n' if platform.system().lower()=='windows' else '-c'
    command = ['ping', parameter, '1', host]
    response = subprocess.call(command)

    if response == 0:
        return True
    #Will Send email if response from ping is false (aka not pingable/down)
    else:

        gmail_user = 'email'
        gmail_password = 'password'

        sent_from = gmail_user
        to = ['recepient']
        subject = 'subject'
        body = 'body'

        email_text = """\
        From: %s
        To: %s
        Subject: %s

        %s
        """ % (sent_from, ", ".join(to), subject, body)

        try:
            smtp_server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
            smtp_server.ehlo()
            smtp_server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
            smtp_server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
            smtp_server.close()
            print ("Email sent successfully!")
        except Exception as ex:
            print ("Something went wrong….",ex)
    
    #delay so i dont recieve spam emails while the 'while' loop runs
    time.sleep(43000)


print(myping("ip to ping"))
```

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously can't change the behavior of `ping`.  However, you can certainly use `subprocess.check_output`, which returns the output of the command, and parse that.

Using `ping` like this is not particularly useful.  There are many reasons why you can't reach a remote host.  Perhaps your local network is down, or your router has died, or your cable has been unplugged.